# How to create tooltip tutorial for application to show on first start up of app in xamarin UWP and Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android, tooltip

I know we can use "VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver" for showing only once after installation of the app.
but how to show the tooltips for an actual view or tutorial on the first launch?

are there any libraries that I can use?
Please Help Me

```
OtoMainPage = new NavigationPage(new Oto_Test_RootPage()) { Title = "Nova-Link", BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#1979CA"), IconImageSource = "Test.png", BarTextColor = Color.White };                 
if (VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver)
{              

    MainPage = OtoMainPage; // on first launch        

}      

else           

{            

    MainPage = OtoMainPage; // normal launch     

}
```

Comment: In apps I've worked on (not necessarily Xamarin), this was "faked". Its easy enough to take a screenshot on a "typical" device, and write custom code that responds to touch on hard-coded rectangles. This is then "scaled" (stretched) to the user's device's dimensions. I don't have an example of such code, but its straightforward coding in any language and platform. One screen size image, one touch handler, a list of rectangles with associated actions. Some research required, if these are not familiar concepts.